# Windows 10 tablet taskbar crashes when trying to bring up on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, on-screen-keyboard

Starting about 2 weeks ago, my Dell Venue 8 Pro (Z3740D 2GB RAM) started acting up. When I am trying to type in text boxes, the on-screen keyboard does not pop up. This is the same regardless in Tablet Mode or Desktop Mode. When I try to press the keyboard on the taskbar, it does not pop up either. Other taskbar icons, like wi-fi, battery, etc seems to work fine. If I press keyboard multiple times, say 50, the taskbar will eventually crash. Only after taskbar restarted, the keyboard will pop-up (but that whole process takes half a minute or so).

I don't think I installed any new application or device lately. It is all regular updates. My most recent update is 1803. Does anyone know how I should go about troubleshoot and fix it? I have a feeling that the problem happens after pressing the TaskView icon, the keyboard will likely to fail to launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some items to check. if one of them fixes the problem, there is no need
to continue on in the list.

1. In *Start > Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard*,
   verify that "On-Screen Keyboard" is "On".
2. Use regedit to go to
   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI`,
   and verify that `ShowTabletKeyboard` is `1`.
3. Run `osk.exe` to launch the On-screen Keyboard, click the "Options" key.
   At the bottom of the "Options" dialog click/touch the blue link
   "Control whether the On-Screen Keyboard starts when I sign in"
   and in the new dialog verify that "Use On-Screen Keyboard" is checked.
   Select "Apply" and then "OK" twice to close all dialogs.
4. In *PC Settings > Devices*, select *Typing* on the left.
   In the resulting dialog ensure that
   "Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there’s no keyboard attached to your device" is Enabled.
5. Run `services.msc` and verify that the
   *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel* service is running and is set
   to start automatically.
6. Run
   [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
   to verify Windows integrity.
7. Create a new user profile/account and check if the problem arrives when
   logging in with it. If the problem disappears then your current user profile
   is corrupted.

Comment: I was having trouble typing so I have to postpone my reply until I have a keyboard. The "On-Screen Keyboard" from Ease of Access belongs to a different type of keyboard. It is harder to type and also difficult to resize. Most importantly, it does not pop-up and auto-hide like the taskbar keyboard. Also, the keyboard config in the "Typing" setting is actually "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached". So I don't really need it turned on.

Comment: So ignore point 2 above; the rest does pertain to the keyboard you are using.

Comment: Looks like the "sfc /scannow" fixed it! It took a while a run but I have used the tablet for 30 min and the keyboard seems to always pop up at the right time!

Comment: This means that some Windows files were corrupted. Just in case, I suggest an anti-virus scan.

Comment: The problem came back and "sfc /scannow" does not fix it this time. Virus scan didn't find anything. I think I am about to throw in the towel and have the window reset.

Comment: That is the safest course for an unexplained ongoing corruption. Mind your backups.